# user input and database include '%' and using LIKE '%xx%' to search for the input in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    BrokerData.BrokerName,
    Product.BAID, 
    Product.ProductName,
    Product.ProductName,
    Product.Type,
    Product.RevenueFactor,
    Product.VolumeFactor,
    Product.PriceFactor 
FROM Product
INNER JOIN BrokerData 
ON Product.BAID = BrokerData.BAID 
WHERE (ProductName Like '%xxx%' OR BaseProductName Like '%xxx%');
```

This query will help the users search for the product that contains "xxx". However, the database includes % in some of the product name, hence, when users input is 1%, it will give the product that contains "1".

I've tried to use CONTAINS, but it doesn't help for this.
The follwing is the query that I used CONTAINS but it doesn't work also:

```
SELECT
    BrokerData.BrokerName,
    Product.BAID,
    Product.ProductName,
    Product.ProductName, 
    Product.Type,
    Product.RevenueFactor,
    Product.VolumeFactor,
    Product.PriceFactor
FROM Product
INNER JOIN BrokerData 
ON Product.BAID = BrokerData.BAID
WHERE CONTAINS ((ProductName Like '%xxx%') 
OR CONTAINS (BaseProductName Like '%xxx%'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.
Replace your user input with % to \%

Example Demo Code:

```
CREATE TABLE data_with_percent(
data VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO data_with_percent VALUES('1%');
INSERT INTO data_with_percent VALUES('2%');
INSERT INTO data_with_percent VALUES('1');

SELECT * FROM data_with_percent WHERE data LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE('1%', '%', '\%'),'%');
```

Testing as following:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b607/1)

Thank you.

Comment: I've changed to escape '|%' but it shown that "No data Found". Data not found when user types something that is not inside the database. But I am sure that 1% is inside the database. But thanks for you help :)

Comment: Hey, I edited the reply with demo mysql code. You can try with it.

Comment: Is it because when user input is "1%", my code will run the query and replace '%xxx|%%' with  '1%|%%'?

Comment: your code should 
replace the '1%' to '1|%'
then pass to the query 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE data like %'.$input.'%'

Comment: but sometime the user input might be vary. for instance, '1%Company' or '%CF'.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the query and also reference to Reno reply. 
You try change the 1% to your user input.

Answer (score 2):

You need a escape code `\` before `%` which your input contains a `%`.

If `xxx` is '1%', do it like this;)

```
ProductName LIKE '%1\%%'
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68009/3)

Also, see the MySQL Manual page on [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: it give me "Bad JSON escape sequence: \%. " after I use the code. Anyway, thanks for your help:

Comment: @kllow 'Bad JSON escape sequence: \%', this is what mysql gives you or somewhere else?

Comment: somewhere else, because i use json.

Comment: It's hard to figure it out without more codes about this error, and what you asked in this question is you want to find a query sql. @kllow